# Residue of a point defined by a function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

> Let $\varphi:U \to U $ be analytic with $\varphi'(a) \neq 0$, show that for any analytic function $f$ on $U \smallsetminus \{\varphi(a)\}$ that
>   $$\operatorname{res}(f, \varphi(a)) = \operatorname{res}((f \circ \varphi) \varphi',a) $$

I have noticed that the form seems similar to when we integrate along a curve $C$ parameterised by some $g:[a,b] \to \mathbb{C}$:
$$\int_C f(z) \,dz = \int_a^bf(g(t))g'(t) \,dt $$

But can't actually get this to work in this case:
$$\operatorname{res}(f, \varphi(a)) := \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\delta B_\varepsilon(\varphi(a))} f(z) \,dz $$

The boundary is dependent on $\varphi(a)$, but the curve is not parameterised by this?

I'm not really sure how to go further?

Does $\varphi$ being analytic mean that since $\varepsilon$ is small that the ball around $\varphi(a)$ is still "ball shaped" and now it's boundary is parametersied by $\varphi(B_\varepsilon (a))$, or is there some better approach?